# Run Rspec controller test on PUT method correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am writing a Rspec controller test on one of my model's update function. The model i'm testing is `Order`.

When I run controller test, I see order_attributes are not updating now.

Below is order_controller.rb:

```
      before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

        def update
            if @order.update(order_params)
                render json: @order, status: :ok, location: @order
            else
                render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
            end
        end

        private
            # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
            def set_order
                @order = Order.find(params[:id])
            end

      def order_params
        params.permit(:order_type)
      end
        end
```

controller spec I have is like following:

```
    let(:order) {
        FactoryGirl.create(:order)
  }

    describe "PUT #update" do
        context "valid attributes" do
             it "changes order's attributes" do
                 put :update, id: order.id, order_params: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:order, user_id: 19)
                 order.reload
                 expect(assigns(:order).user_id).to match(order.user_id)
             end
            end
        end
```

Here is FactoryGirl for order model:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :order do
    order_type Order.order_types[:serviceA]
    association :user

    before(:create) do |order|
      order.user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end
  end
end
```

In the controller test, I see order_attributes are not updating. Even If I update user_id to 19, it is not reflected. Am I passing order_params in a wrong way?

Comment: What does your `order_params` method look like in the controller?

Comment: @ChrisPeters, I've updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how it appears that you have things setup, it looks like you'll need to define your own `order_params` method with permitted parameters from `params[:order]`.

So this needs to be added to the `private` section of your controller:

```
def order_params
  # Add other attributes that you want to allow on the `order` object.
  params.require(:order).permit(:user_id, :order_type)
end
```

Then the call to `put` in your test should look like this:

```
put :update, id: order.id, order: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:order, user_id: 19)
```

Read more about [strong parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) in the Rails guides.

Comment: What if I do not have `require(:order)`? I updated orders_controller.rb

Comment: You'll need to call either `fetch` or `require` and chain `permit` off of that. (You'll likely want to use `require`.) Read the docs that I linked you to if you need more info.

Comment: One more question. in my Order.rb, I set order_type as `presence:true`. When I pass update `order_type` as `nil`, it should not update. But it does update to nil. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure what to tell you on that one. You may want to ask it as a separate question.